# Will LG Ultrafine 5k work with 2012 MacBook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos

I just purchased a 2016 MacBook Pro but have a 2012 MBP Retina I use for work.  I'm considering buying the LG Ultrafine 5k and I'm wondering, will I be able to use the display with my 2012 MBP?  I don't mind if I don't get full resolution while using the 2012, I just want to know if it will work.

Comment: Dave, did you ever resolve this? I'm in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the Ultrafine 5k only has thunderbolt 3 over USB-C inputs, so you'll need a thunderbolt 2 to USB-C cable to even connect. You should be able to run the monitor at a greatly reduced resolution which is then "upscaled" to 5k. For instance, many people run 4K monitors at 1080p, so the 5k should work at 1080p (or other resolutions <5K) as well.

Upscaling is very common on TVs at the moment, since there is a lack of 4k content, and thus those watching 1080p content on 4k TVs must have their content upscaled. I've attached an article on C|Net discussing [upscaling](https://www.cnet.com/news/can-4k-tvs-make-1080p-look-better/).

Thus in principle it should work. I'd contact the manufacturer directly to make sure. That monitor is not cheap.

Comment: For a 5K monitor, you might prefer to run at 1440p over 1080p, assuming that's possible. 1440p is exactly half the width and height of a 5K display, so icons and other bitmapped art will scale evenly.

Answer (score 1):

I was connecting my old MBP mid-2015 to the LG Ultrafine 5k, and out of curiosity I also hooked up my old MBP 2012. Works like a charm running 2560x1440 resolution @ 60hz. Use a CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 dock and an Apple TB3 to TB2 adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

Officially the 2012 MBP isn't going to be able to use the LG UltraFine 5K. For more information you can read [Use the LG UltraFine 5K Display with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT207448).

Now, sometimes what Apple officially supports isn't the full story, so it *may* be you  could find a way to get this to work. Only you can decide if that's a risk worth taking.